# Magento 2 from which file shipping methods displaying

Tags: magento-2.1, shipping-methods

I am trying to change checkout page on shipping methods display pattern. According to template path hints i checked onepage.phtml in that i did't get the related script.In which file i have to check. can u please any one help in this

[image]

Comment: check at magento-root/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html

Comment: Thanks Emipro Team, Can you please explain how data is binding from which js file.

Comment: please check : magento-root/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js

Comment: @Emipro Team, I renamed shipping.html  as shipping.html-bak but  still data is loading....

Comment: Where you have renamed in vendor or pub directory ?

Comment: In vendor and  deploy and upgrade files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62383/discussion-between-ramesh-and-emipro-technologies-pvt-ltd).

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd.I have check it two file but not remove shipping method

Answer (score 0):

You should clear the cache using this command:
**php bin/magento cache:clean** 
and in order to change or add something to each shipping method then you can overwrite these two files **shipping-method-list.html** and **shipping-method-item.html** located in **/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address** folder.